# Python API json file to Pandas dataframe in Jupyter

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I’m new to Python and Jupyter. I have an API which I get my data from. I have located the childnode with the list of data I want from a loop. And now I want to put that data into Pandas dataframe. Could someone please help me with this? You can see my code below

```
resp = requests.get('http://***
auth=('***', '***'),
headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})

data = json.loads(resp.text)
    for Observasjoner in data ['Holdings']:
display(Observasjoner)
```

Answer (score 0):

just extract the data from JSON and append it into the lists, later create a data frame and save it into the data frame.

```
import requests
data = requests.get("form_link")
print(data.text()) #will print all text or use print(data.json())
```

Now search for the data which you need or use beautiful soup for if it is in HTML website

if it is JSON they will be like dictionaries so use the same concepts here, now my data is the dictionary

```
      print(data["key"])  #it will print key in same way iterate full dictionary (JSON FILE)
```

Now use the dictionary concept and append all the values of the keys into the lists

now keys are the columns and values are the rows create a data frame for it

Thanks

Comment: for Observasjoner in data ['Holdings']:
    print(Observasjoner['EopLocInterestAccrual'],Observasjoner['EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice'])

Comment: If I do like the code above it doesen't come out in a dataframe only like a list. Keep in mind I'm new to this